# Find unique values depend on another column value with drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I just want to find unique sales orders in below chart. Some sales orders are common for both work centers. Sales order 1000146203.

```
=IF(A2=$E$1,(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)=1)*1)
```

This formula works. But after I select TR002 it missed common sales ordrs for TR001 & TR002 i mentioned above. How to find unique sales orders as 1 & Fales after I change workcenter using drop down($E$1).

[image]

Work Center Sales Order Unique or Not

```
TR001   2000020429  =IF(A2=$E$1,(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)=1)*1)
TR001   1000146203  FALSE
TR001   1000146275  FALSE
TR001   1000147389  FALSE
TR002   1000144516  1
TR002   1000146203  0
TR002   2000020880  1
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I'm having difficulty understanding what you're goal is. Please [edit] your question to include more details regarding what you're trying to accomplish, and what the issue with your current approach is. Thanks!

Comment: (1) I don’t understand what you’re asking for. Please [edit] your question to explain it more clearly. For example, (a) explain the role of `E1` in your question, (b) give examples of the results you want (explaining *why* they are the results you want, if there’s any possibility of ambiguity), (c) explain why you expect the formula to have to give you those results, and (d) present the actual results that you are getting. (2) [Please don’t post images of text.](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want.  Include the output data you expect from your input data (clearly identifying which is which) and give a clearer description of the computation you want Excel to do.  … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Sales Order `1000146203` is duplicate if consider column B only but if include Work center one is with `TR001` & other with `TR002` therefore no unique. But if you use this `=IF(A2=$E$1,(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)>1)*1)` then you find `1` in `C7` with `TR002` `1000146203`. Is that u are looking for , or any other ? But the problem is that the formula doesn't works properly with `TR001` !!.

Answer (score 0):

**I thinks that you are looking for this in terms of extracting "unique Sales order matching Work Center".**

[image]

*Write this Array formula in Cell `E4`, finish with **`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`** & fill down.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$10, MATCH(0, IF($E$2=$B$4:$B$10, COUNTIF($E$3:$E3, $C$4:$C$10), ""), 0)),"")}
```

**Note,**

- **Since OP's Data doesn't contains `DUPLICATEs` so that formula
  extracts  all four `Sales Order` in case one (`Screen Shot 1`)**.
- But in `Screen Shot 2`, you can find `DUPLICATEs` in `Sales Order` &
  the formula extracts `3 Unique Sales order`.
- And in case of `TR002` formula will extract all `3` `Sales Order` since
  has no `DUPLICTATEs`.